# Is access speed <- proportional to - > path length in a filesystem?

Tags: linux, windows, performance, path, filesystems

### Premise

- I have 10k files and want to open a specific one.

---

### Scenario 1:

- I have **one** folder with **10k files** in it
- I write a program that opens the file with the path `"D:/Data/5432.file"`

---

### Scenario 2:

- I have **many folders and subfolders** that are structured like a binary tree
- [first folders: **"<5k"** | **">5k"** --> inside of them the subfolders **"<2.5k"** | **">2.5k"** - **"<7.5k"** | **">7.5k"** --> and so on until there is only one file in the last subfolder]
- Now I again write a program that opens the file but this time the path is longer: `"D:/Data/>5k/<7.5k/.../5432.file"`
- Note that my program does **NOT** interpret the folder names. They are random strings in its eyes.

So the only difference is the **path length** of the file I want to open.

---

### Now the question is:

- Is the program in scenario 2 faster to open the file, because it has a more specific path
- or does following the path need the same or even more time than just searching for the filename in scenario 1?

---

Edit:

### Additional Info:

- CPU - Intel Xeon e3-1231 v3.
- OS - Ubuntu Server 22.04.2
- the OS is installed on SSD but the files will be stored on HDD (at least for now)

Comment: Paths needs to be read by the OS and converted to FS nodes. This process take some time but it is generally fast. The speed is dependent of the target CPU and the target OS (not to mention the type of FS). The relative speed is highly dependent of the specific storage device. SSD and HDD behave very differently for such a task. This question is already hard to answer with such information, so it is (nearly) impossible to answer without them. Please add much more details. That being said, I think the best thing is simply to benchmark the possible options.

Comment: If you use a HDD, doing a binary search with nested directory is probably very inefficient. Having a big structured file can be significantly faster, if possible. Alternatively, "Scenario 1" is fine, but AFAIK, some FS have a limited number of file per directory.

Comment: I agree with *"some FS have a limited number of file per directory"*. You'll have to spend time digging in FileSystem documentation (And testing to confirm!). Good luck.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks for your reply, that already helps a lot. I added some additional Info. Note that the whole thing is only theory atm and I didn't expect a precise time estimation but rather a vague recommendation, of which approach would achieve a better performance. From how I interpret your answer the best solution would be a mix of both, where I have x amount of folders with y amount of files in it. After testing I can finetune x and y, to get the best performance out of the system. Thoughts?

Comment: I would personally start with a ~40 directory of 256 files. This should be small enough for most FS limits, not too many directory for mainstream OS directory caches, and it require just 1 directory indirection if the OS do not have it in cache.